# Opening terminal in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, fish

I was trying to make fish my default shell, and it works in iterm2, but every time I try to open the terminal in vscode I get this error:

```
The terminal process failed to launch: Path to shell executable "/bin/fish" does not exist.
```

These are my iterm2 settings:
[image]

I am on macOS. How can I solve this issue?

Note: Opening vscode form the terminal using the `code` command works.

Comment: `/bin/fish` is an unusual path for fish - usually it's at `/usr/local/bin/fish`. What does `which fish` show?

Comment: your iterm2 profile is a bash shell that opens a fish subshell.........

Comment: @ridiculous_fish
It returns:
/opt/homebrew/bin/fish

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to change your shell on both Linux and macOS is via the `chsh` command. The steps are:

1. Add the shell path to the text file `/etc/shells`, if not already present. This usually needs to be done as root, but only has to be done once.
2. Use `chsh -s` to permanently switch shells.

Example:

```bash
> echo /opt/homebrew/bin/fish | sudo tee -a /etc/shells
> chsh -s /opt/homebrew/bin/fish
```

and now your shell is /opt/homebrew/bin/fish.

on macOS, there is another way:

1. Go to System Settings -> Users and Groups
2. Right click on your user and choose Advanced Options
3. From here you can change your login shell

Comment: Thanks, this seems to have changed my default shell in iterm, however, now when I open vscode I get this error:

Unable to resolve your shell environment: A system error occurred (spawn /bin/fish ENOENT)